# How to match a variable with value in Python

Tags: python

I am at a loss trying to figure out how to achieve the following in Python. I have a variable that has a string inside it

variable = "Normal" or variable = "Unknown"

I just want to write an If statement that will check the value of the variable and execute some code based on it.

In Perl i'd simply write

```
if ( $variable =~ /Normal/ ) {
    dosomething()
} elsif ( $variable =~ /Unknown/ ) {
    dosomething()
} else {
    raiseerror()
}
```

How do I achieve the same in Python ?

Comment: if you want to check equality you could do `variable == 'Normal'` if you want to check that it contains you could do `'Normal' in variable` if you want a regex you should look up the `re` module

Comment: @termcap In case you're unaware, the downvotes you've received are likely because the community heavily frowns on direct translation tasks, especially when we don't have evidence that you've tried the problem yourself. For all I know, you spent hours laboring over the problem, but we can't tell that from what you have written. Examples of your best efforts and the exact errors you're encountering will improve the quality of the question.

Comment: @HansMusgrave actually I did spend around two days trying to figure this out, but because I am from the Perl background, I was not expecting python to simply work like bash. I was looking at matches and regexes etc. The reason I used the term "translate" was to make the question easy for people to answer and keep it simple, but it seems to have backfired :)

Comment: @termcap I don't think it was the term "translate" so much as the question not having evidence of the work you did and the specific problems you ran into. One of the purposes of StackOverflow is as an index for how to solve particular problem types, and as written your question probably doesn't directly apply to anyone else. By including the specific behaviors you **did** observe and what you want instead, we might attract users with the same **kinds** of questions and additionally be able to provide a more tailored response from a teaching perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was it intentional to have the same `dosomething()` in both the `if` and the `elsif`? If so, you can get away with the following:

```
if variable in ('Normal', 'Unknown'):
    dosomething()
else:
    raise Exception
```

Otherwise, you'll need to actually translate the `elsif` over to python as well:

```
if variable == "Normal":
    dosomething()
elif variable == "Unknown":
    dosomethingelse()
else:
    raise Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if variable == "Normal":
    #do something
elif variable == "Unknown":
    #do something else
else:
    #do another thing
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Perl regex here. So, a mapping solution in Python would be:

```
import re

if re.search("Normal", variable):
    do_something()
elif re.search("Unknown", variable):
    do_something()
else:
    raise Exception("Error")
```

In Python regular expressions are available in `re` module. First argument to `re.search` is like regular expression you would write in Perl.